# How to get parameter values out of json post

Tags: python, json, api, maps, bing

I am trying to use the bing maps api to get travel time and distance between 2 gps coordinates.
I get a json answer, however, I am not able to get the values out of this dictionary ?

```py
import requests
import json

payload = {
    "origins": [{"latitude": 50.781869, "longitude": 4.596188}],
    "destinations": [{"latitude": 50.87650130092019, "longitude": 4.671327819416231}],
    "travelMode": "driving",
}

paramtr = {"key": "mybingAPIkey"}

r = requests.post('https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix', data = json.dumps(payload), params = paramtr)


print(r.json())
```

gives the following result:

```py
{
  'authenticationResultCode': 'ValidCredentials',
  'brandLogoUri': 'http: //dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png',
  'copyright': 'Copyright © 2023 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.',
  'resourceSets': [
    {
      'estimatedTotal': 1,
      'resources': [
        {
          '__type': 'DistanceMatrix:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1',
          'destinations': [
            {
              'latitude': 50.87650130092019,
              'longitude': 4.671327819416231
            }
          ],
          'origins': [
            {
              'latitude': 50.781869,
              'longitude': 4.596188
            }
          ],
          'results': [
            {
              'destinationIndex': 0,
              'originIndex': 0,
              'totalWalkDuration': 0,
              'travelDistance': 14.511,
              'travelDuration': 21.9667
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  'statusCode': 200,
  'statusDescription': 'OK',
  'traceId': '7fecad5b38b94df9acef6287488b68c9|DU0000273D|0.0.0.0|DU000005E8'
}
```

now: how do I get the travelDistance out of this ? (14.511 in this case)
or the travelDuration ? (21.9667)

tried to get the key and value pairs, but not really getting further with this.

with some other code, I got the keys :

authenticationResultCode
brandLogoUri
copyright
resourceSets
statusCode
statusDescription
traceId

Comment: the value you want is nested in a dictionary nested inside a list in a dictionary in a list in a dictionary in a list in a dictionary. try this: `r.json()['resourceSets'][0]['resources'][0]['results'][0]['travelDistance']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `json.loads()` and pass the content of your response. Then access values like you do from a dictionary:

```
r = requests.post('https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix', data = json.dumps(payload), params = paramtr)    

dt = json.loads(r.content)

travelDistance = dt['resourceSets'][0]['resources'][0]['results'][0]['travelDistance']

travelDuration = dt['resourceSets'][0]['resources'][0]['results'][0]['travelDuration']
```

Comment: travelDistance = dt['resourceSets'][0]['resources'][0]['results'][0]['travelDistance']

travelDuration = dt['resourceSets'][0]['resources'][0]['results'][0]['travelDuration']

when adding the [0], it also works indeed. Thx !

without the [0], I got the following : TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str